# Reflecting Stack Overflow's activity log in Facebook activity

Tags: feature-request, sharing, facebook

It can increase engagement on questions asked or commented on or answered. If a user who asks the question has the same post in his Facebook profile with related Stack Overflow link and the same for comments and answers, letting you earn a new badge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There already *are* a badges for this:

- [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses.
- [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses.
- [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.

All you have to do is use the *Share* link under a post:

[image: sharing]

It even comes with a Facebook option!

The link contains the post number and your userid (`/q/<postid>/<userid>` for questions, `/a/<postid>/<userid>` for answers), so that any clicks on the links can be tallied towards the badges. Only clicks from *outside* the Stack Exchange network count.

Comment: I asked to get it shared automatically..Just Like Quora!!

Comment: Suggesting that we make this site more like Facebook or Quora is not likely to be welcomed with an outpouring of support, @Harsh. In fact, quite the opposite.